# Replace values in two dimensional associative array

Tags: php, replace, foreach, associative-array

$update is a two dimensional associative array. Part of the var_dump is:

```
array(101) { 
[0]=> array(27) { ["code"]=> string(4) "2014" ["na1"]=> string(4) "6010" and many more fields following }
[1]=> array(27) { ["code"]=> string(4) "2015" ["na1"]=> string(4) "6010" and many more fields following }
and many more subarrays following of course . . .
```

Need to replace the code value with a name and created:

```
    foreach($update as $key=>$subarray){;
        foreach ($subarray as $subkey=>$val) {
            echo $subkey.$val."<br>";//Just for checking
            if ($subkey=='code' && $val==2014) 
            {
                $val="Name1";
            }
            elseif ($key=='code' && $val==2015) 
            {
                $val="Name2";
            }
        }
    }
var_dump($update);
```

The echo $subkey and $val give perfectly the correct values, however de If statement seems never to be true (or is cancelled out again somehow) as the var_dump is leading again to the original values

Some Stackoverflow research even showed constructions with only one foreach loop, much more elegant, but seems not to reach the second array level.

Is there a better approach? Solution to fix this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the source array.

```
foreach($update as $key=>$subarray){
    foreach ($subarray as $subkey=>$val) {
        echo $subkey.$val."<br>";//Just for checking
        if ($subkey=='code' && $val==2014) 
        {
            //$val="Name1";
            $update[$key][$subkey] = "Name1" ;
        }
        elseif ($key=='code' && $val==2015) 
        {
            //$val="Name2";
            $update[$key][$subkey] = "Name2" ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Small issue, big consequences. Thanks for staying close to the "problem code".

Comment: Just notice my own semicolon after the first foreach . . . you kept it also . . . is that correct!

Comment: @John dont need that. I copy paste your code. i will remove that.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the field you want by index.

Example :

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach($update as $key=>$subarray){;
        foreach ($subarray as $subkey=>$val) {
            echo $subkey.$val."<br>";//Just for checking
            if ($subkey=='code' && $val==2014) 
            {
                $update[$i][$j] = "Name1";
            }
            elseif ($key=='code' && $val==2015) 
            {
                $update[$i][$j] = "Name2";
            }
            $j++
        }
        $j = 0;
        $i++;
    }
var_dump($update);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArr = array(); 
foreach($update as $key=>$subarray){
        $subNewArr = array();
        foreach ($subarray as $item) {
            if ($item['code']==2014) 
            {
                $item['code']="Name1";
            }
            elseif ($item['code']==2015) 
            {
                $item['code']="Name2";
            }
            array_push($subNewArr, $item);

        }
        array_push($newArr, $subNewArr);
    }
var_dump($update);
```

Less if else checking

Comment: Works well, nice solution. Main issue though seemed to be my addressing of the value to change. $val = was not updating, which you corrected! Thanks